# How to create insert button on each row?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

See the image below.
[image]
When i click on any register button the last row gets inserted instead of the row which i need.

What i need is: if i click register, the entire selected row must store in another table.

Whats wrong here?
Please help me..

```
<table class="table table-striped jambo_table table-bordered"> <thead> <tr> <th width="75px">Semester:</th> <th width="110px">Subject Code:</th> <th>Subject Name:</th> <th width="110px">Exam Type:</th> <th  width="110px">Marks:</th> <th width="75px">Action:</th> </tr> </thead> <?php
    $view_users_query="select * from details WHERE regd_no='" .$_SESSION['regd_no']. "'";//select query for viewing users.
    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
    {
        $slno=$row[0];
        $sem=$row[5];
        $subject_code=$row[9];
        $subject_name=$row[10];
    ?> <tr> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="yes" name="sem1" id="sem1" value="<?php echo $sem;?>"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="yes" name="subject_code1" id="subject_code1" value="<?php echo $subject_code;  ?>"></td> 
    <td ><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="yes" name="subject_name1" id="subject_name1" value="<?php echo $subject_name;  ?>"></td> 
    <td> <select class="form-control" id="etype" name="etype"> <option value="">Select-Exam-Type</option> 
    <option value="Backlog">Backlog</option> 
    <option value="Improvement">Improvement</option> 
    <option value="Special Exam">Special Exam</option> 
    </select> </td> 
    <td><select class="form-control" id="marks" name="marks"> <option value="">Marks</option> 
    <option value="100">100</option> 
    <option value="60">60</option> 
    <option value="30">30</option> </select></td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="register/<?php echo $subject_code?>" class="btn btn-success form-control" value="Register" > </td> 
    <!--btn btn-danger is a bootstrap button to show danger--> </tr> 
    <?php
}
    ?><br> 
    <?php                   
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
$regn=$_POST['regn'];//here getting result from the post array after submitting the form.
$name=$_POST['name'];//same
$branch=$_POST['branch'];
$batch=$_POST['batch'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$center=$_POST['center'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$sem1=$_POST['sem1'];
$subject_code1=$_POST['subject_code1'];
$subject_name1=$_POST['subject_name1'];
$etype=$_POST['etype'];
$marks=$_POST['marks'];
 }
$insert_user="insert into registered (regd_no,name,branch,batch,email,mobile,center,sem,subject_code,subject_name,date,etype,marks) VALUE ('$regn','$name','$branch','$batch','$email','$mobile','$center','$sem1','$subject_code1','$subject_name1','$date','$etype','$marks')";
   if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_user))
{
echo "<script>alert('You have Succesfully registered $subject_code1 - $subject_name1 ')</script>";
    echo"<script>window.open('','_self')</script>";
}
}
?> </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look over your if-statement. It says:

If rows is more then 0 then echo out:

```
<script>alert('Subject Name $subject_name1 with Subject Code $subject_code1 is already registered')</script>
```

Then you have your insert row in just {} with nowhere pointing at if it is a under the if-statement or anything.

Comment: That is to limit times of inset function

Comment: You can limit it with LIMIT=1 in the query. That would make it to limit it to just one item at the time.